# Why is the system32\drivers\etc folder not displayed in Notepad++ when opened as Administrator in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, notepad++

I am logged in as a user who has Adminstrative privileges on my standalone (not part of a domain) PC, which is running Windows 7 x64 Ultimate, and I've opened Notepad++ "as administrator", yet I cannot see the \etc folder beneath system32\drivers.  I want to edit the hosts file there.  In file browser, I can see the \etc folder is present, along with many other folders that are not displayed in the Notepad++ open-file dialog. Is this a permissions issue or a Notepad++ issue?

Comment: Did you try right clicking on the hosts file and select "Open with Notepad++".  This works if your goal is to edit the file.

Comment: You can put the full path by hand in the path field in the file dialog.  This is the best way to view hidden system folders.

Comment: @Bryan: it can be done as you suggested; but I was wondering if there was a way to reveal these hidden folders to Notepad++, since then it could be done in one step rather than two -- I wouldn't have to browse to the location first with File Browser (I don't always remember the path exactly).

Comment: You can expose hidden files on your machine via the "Folder Options" control panel -> View -> "Show Hidden Files, Folders or Drives".  OR....you could un-hide the file.  From the command line  "Attrib -h c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts" might want to do the "etc" folder too while you are at it..  Though I don't remember that folder being hidden by default.

Comment: FreeCommander XE 2018   Build 770 32-bit public seems to have the same issue.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The issue is [folder redirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), If a 32 bit program attempts to access the System32 folder it will be invisibly redirected to the `%windir%\SysWOW64` directory, this is for 32/64 bit application compatibility.

All the files in System32 are 64 bit, however if a program was incorrectly written they may have hard-coded the System32 in to their program when looking for a DLL. To prevent random program crashes from incorrectly written programs Microsoft does that redirect.

Now if you look at that link I posted at the top `%windir%\system32\drivers\etc` is exempt from this redirection, that is why if you go directly there it works fine, but if you are in `%windir%\system32\drivers` you are really looking at the `%windir%\SysWoW64\drivers` folder which does not contain a `etc` subfolder.

There are a few workarounds

1. you need to either directly enter `%windir%\system32\drivers\etc`
2. navigate to the "hidden" folder `%windir%\sysnative` which will take you to the "real" `System32` folder and you can go up the directory tree like normal.
3. When you are in `%windir%\System32\drivers` manually click the address bar and add on the `\etc` to the folder path (this is really just another way of doing method #1)

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's x32 issue. x32 Notepad++ maybe can't see "etc" folder right on x64 OS. No x64 version exists yet. Try NPP forum for some workaround.

Comment: 32-bit programs can see 64-bit system32 folder via `sysnative`. And there's 64-bit Notepad++ at this point of time although less developed than the 32-bit version

Answer (score 0):

I have unlocked administrator account 
here is how to do it: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/enable-the-hidden-administrator-account-on-windows-vista/

And now i can see it

Comment: dont know is it notpead++ or windows problem :(

Comment: It is not an administrative problem, it is a 32/64 bit problem. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem and found the explanations here helpful but the answer is even simpler than they suggest - you don't have to type the whole path name in or do any any folder redirection.  When you run Notepad++ as Administrator and use File, Open you can navigate to the drivers folder and just add into the Filename dialog box: /etc/hosts (or any other file you want to open) - it opens immediately.